# Adding text underneath anchors

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="/location/810"><img class="locationthumb" src="/act/locationthumb/810"></a>
<a href="/location/785"><img class="locationthumb" src="/act/locationthumb/785"></a>
<a href="/location/424"><img class="locationthumb" src="/act/locationthumb/424"></a>
<a href="/location/808"><img class="locationthumb" src="/act/locationthumb/808"></a>
<a href="/location/904"><img class="locationthumb" src="/act/locationthumb/904"></a>
```

They align up next to each other well. Here is an image:

[image: lined up images]

How can I add text underneath each image?

Here is my CSS:

```
.locationthumb {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

Comment: But this is too broad. How do you want them to be placed? Is the text to be clickable? Are the text same for all(can use CSS `content: " "`)?

Comment: @ManojKumar directly underneath

Comment: `Left` and `top` properties will not work without relatively or absolutely positioning them (basically non-statically) positioning them

Comment: Is the number of images fixed or does it need to be dynamic?

Comment: Its fixed at 5 but if you want to perform it dynamically you can. but fixed is fine